# Jenkins test result trend graph only appears when project is disabled

Tags: jenkins

For some reason one of my projects has gotten into a state where the dashboard only displays the graph when the project is disabled:

[image]

As soon as I re-enable the project it disappears inexplicably:

[image]

Other almost identically configured projects work fine, and the chart remains visible whether the project is enabled or disabled.

[image]

I've tried workarounds I've seen for really old (~2012) manifestations of a similar bug [[1]](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13043?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel) [[2]](http://sellotapetest.blogspot.ca/2011/08/test-result-trend-not-appearing-in.html), like renaming the project, but nothing I've done so far has been able to correct this issue. Note that the test results themselves don't go away, I can still view them at /testReport/, just the graph is inexplicably disappearing.

This is using Jenkins ver. 1.554.2

I have a hard time believing this is a bug, is there maybe a dashboard configuration page I'm not aware of that might have gotten messed with?

Comment: You have obvisouly looked around -just a couple of things? Do you see the same behavire in a different browser? not sure what you are using i would recommand chrome - also I assume a restart has already been done ? and have you tried cloning this project to see if it happens again ?

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: This is more of a bug report than a question.

Comment: I agree, this should be raised as a bug in Jenkins plugin.

Comment: Should have been a jenkins bug report rather than a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because "Projects are_csharp" does not have at least one 100% passing run. Test result trend will be shown only when you have at least one 100% passing result.

From the images it is evident that "Projects are_platform" has many 100% passing results.

Comment: I'm afraid that's simply not true. Both have a large number of passing runs (which is clear when I "disable" the are_csharp project and the results magically appear again). If you're wondering about the yellow area, those are skips (inconclusive) and both projects have those in every result too. You can see a thin yellow line at the bottom of the are_platform project. There's no difference there.

Comment: Skips are treated as failure... a run with 0 failures and 0 skipped needed. This has worked in my case for many of my jenkins test jobs. So I believe you may have some run with 100% passing in are_platform in history. To try things out, can you please have dummy 100% tests passing run and check